# Only use GROUP BY if condition is met

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a table containing articles and a picklist A. Sometimes I need to GROUP the picklist to sum up the articles to be picked as once (eg. article A (3x) ) and in some cases I need to display the items ungrouped (article A (1x), article A (1x), article A (1x) )

Based on the type of the picklist I want to display the results grouped or ongrouped.

Now it would be nice if I could use a condition on GROUP BY

OUTPUT ungrouped

```
ID| EAN            | article | amount
1 | 01234567890123 | A       | 1
2 | 01234567890123 | A       | 2
3 | 01234567890123 | A       | 4
4 | 98695959292929 | B       | 1
5 | 95956562629262 | C       | 5
```

OUTPUT grouped

```
ID| EAN            | article | amount
1 | 01234567890123 | A       | 7
4 | 98695959292929 | B       | 1
5 | 95956562629262 | C       | 5

 SELECT article, ean, type FROM articles 
 GROUP BY articles.ean HAVING type = "grouped" <-- This is just for explainig. It's not a real selection
```

I does not work on this way, but I think it helps to understand my goal.

Depending on the value of the column "type" I want to output the data, grouped or ungrouped.

How can I archieve this?

Comment: Your query does not make sense, because you aren't grouping anything.  How do you want to group?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Hi. You are not explaining what you want. Your example is no use because it just begs the question, we don't know what you mean by it. Give example inputs & outputs and use language to say how the output you want is a function of the input for an arbitrary case. Read & act on [mcve]. Show any relevant code you can manage to write--eg for the two cases separately.

Comment: Ok, updated the question. I just wanted to know how I can use a condition based on a field value, on a GROUP BY .

Comment: I think these kinds of manipulation must be done at application layer than DB layer.

Comment: Hi. The edit helps. Your text & code suggests there's another column `type` input. Does each row have a different value, and you select/partition rows into inputs for the "OUTPUT" cases per some special value (what is it?), and return their `union`, or what? So your question still isn't clear. Please make the effort to use enough words, phrases & sentences to say what you mean plus a complete executable example with input & output. Read & act on [mcve]. Even if you were clear, without an MCVE you are expecting answerers to invent & code data `values` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your `type` is a column or some kind of bind-variable, but it should work like this:

```
SELECT ean, article, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM articles 
GROUP BY ean, article,
         CASE WHEN :type <> 'grouped' THEN id END;
```

If `type` is not `'grouped'`, then the `id` is used as an additional column for grouping, so no rows are grouped together.

See example on [SQL Fidddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e209e/14).